# Makefile and command line different behaviour

Tags: bash, makefile

I am currently working on a bigger project where i want to test executable file with few different codes as input.
I call it like this  `./test < code1`
and after command `echo $?`, it shows last returned value [0, 1, 2, ..]

I wanted to automate is, so i created call in `makefile` like this :

```
#makefile 
[...]
test : 
    ./test < code1 
    @echo $$?
    ./test < code2 
    @echo $$?
    [...]

[...]
```

So i can call `make test`.

When program returns 0 as success, everything works fine. But when program has to return something else than 0, it shows me this :

```
./test < code3
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test[ Error 2
```

Weird thing is, when i try to call program with code which made it crash in command line like :

```
./test < code3; echo $?
```

It works perfectly and shows me last exit status ( for exapmle 3 ).
I am confused now, because i thought it should work the same. Can someone help me out?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Bash syntax in Makefile targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`2>/dev/null\` does not work inside a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47527075/2-dev-null-does-not-work-inside-a-makefile)

Comment: If the test program and the target are both named `test`, you would typically get `make: "test" is up to date` when trying `make test`. i guess your real `Makefile` looks somewhat different.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41452754/939557

You need to put the `echo` into the same logical line as your test invocation:

```
test : 
        ./test < code1; echo $$?
        ./test < code2; echo $$?
```

Comment: Well, i wanted to know, why one specific command works in command line and doesn't work in Makefile..should have asked differently

Comment: I explained it, in the comment that I mentioned.  Each logical line in a makefile recipe is invoked in a separate shell.  It's not like a shell prompt where each command that you type at the prompt is run _in the same shell_.

Comment: If you want to really emulate how make works, from a shell prompt, you need to run `/bin/sh -c 'somecommand'` not just `somecommand`.

Comment: Maybe explain in the answer itself that each recipe line is run in a separate shell.  This is a FAQ but I wasn't quickly able to find a canonical duplicate.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  The answer I linked to says _exacctly_ that.