# Make build to build multiple make files in parallel

Tags: makefile

I have something like the following:
3 libs (libA, libB, libC), libB and libC depends on libA.

Is there anyway to parallel build libB and libC once libA finish building using make ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make: Run several tasks in parallel and wait for completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452476/make-run-several-tasks-in-parallel-and-wait-for-completion)

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/igagis/prorab . If you make your build system using `prorab` it will build `libB` and `libC` in parallel while those libs will still have their own independent `makefile`s.

Answer (score 0):

If your makefile looks like this:

```
all: libA libC libC

libA:
    ...

libB: libA
    ...

libC: libA
    ...
```

then just running `make -j 4` will cause make to parallelize what it can across 4 processes.

you can even parallelize by default by doing this:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -j $$(nproc) libA libB libC

libA:
    ...

libB: libA
    ...

libC: libA
    ...
```